# Return only some object fields in an array using Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, axios, vue-component

So i have those objects in array from an api request

```
(5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {ID: 1, Title: "dqdq", Description: "dqdq", IdUser: 3}
1: {ID: 2, Title: "dqdq", Description: "dqdq", IdUser: 3}
2: {ID: 3, Title: "dqdqddd", Description: "dqdq", IdUser: 3}
3: {ID: 4, Title: "dqdqddd", Description: "dqdq", IdUser: 3}
4: {ID: 5, Title: "dqdqddd", Description: "dqdq", IdUser: 3}
length: 5
```

what i need to have is to take just the Title so i can loop it inside a div and so on for the description and pass it to the child component so i can loop it in the html part

```
<template>
<div>
<Navbar />
<gamesIdeaList :games="games" />
</div>

</template>

<script>
// @ is an alias to /src
import Navbar from '@/components/Navbar.vue'
import gamesIdeaList from '@/components/gamesIdeaList.vue'
import axios from 'axios'
export default {
  name: 'home',
  components: {
    Navbar,
    gamesIdeaList
  },
  data() {
      return {
          games:[]
      }
  },
  //  props: info,
   mounted () {
    axios.get('http://localhost:3001/GamesIdea', {
        headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.usertoken}` }
      })
      .then(res => {
 this.games = res.data.data

console.log(arr)
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
        this.errored = true
      })
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: Please try this 
`this.games = res.data.data.map(d=>{Title: d.Title,Description:d.Description}); `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes can add field you don't want in return

**Solution 1**

```
this.games = res.data.data.map(({
    ID,
    IdUser,
    ...rest
}) => rest);
```

```js
var v1 = [
{ID: 1, Title: "dqdq", Description: "dqdq", IdUser: 3},
{ID: 2, Title: "dqdq", Description: "dqdq", IdUser: 3},
{ID: 3, Title: "dqdqddd", Description: "dqdq", IdUser: 3},
{ID: 4, Title: "dqdqddd", Description: "dqdq", IdUser: 3},
{ID: 5, Title: "dqdqddd", Description: "dqdq", IdUser: 3}]

var games = v1.map(({
    ID,
    IdUser, ...rest}) => rest);

console.log(games);
```

**Solution 2**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25470077/6923146

You can use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
this.games = res.data.data.map(obj => {
    Title: obj.Title,
    Description: obj.Description
});
```

Comment: @anabel please check answer it's updated with new solution

Comment: its working all the solution provided are working , thank you so much

Comment: @anabel, Please accept my answer If it's working fine for you.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

you can Try  this also

````
<div>
<Navbar />
<gamesIdeaList :games="games" />
</div>

</template>

<script>
// @ is an alias to /src
import Navbar from '@/components/Navbar.vue'
import gamesIdeaList from '@/components/gamesIdeaList.vue'
import axios from 'axios'
export default {
  name: 'home',
  components: {
    Navbar,
    gamesIdeaList
  },
  data() {
      return {
          games:[]
      }
  },
  //  props: info,
   mounted () {
    axios.get('http://localhost:3001/GamesIdea', {
        headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.usertoken}` }
      })
      .then(res => {
 this.games = res.data.map(val => {
return {
Title: val.Title,
Description:val.Description}
})

console.log(arr)
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
        this.errored = true
      })
}
}
</script>```
````

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `map` array function as follows :

```
 this.games = res.data.data.map(d=>{Title: d.Title,Description:d.Description});
```

Comment: indeed its working , so i pass two props one for title and one for description ?

Comment: do you want to pass both title and description to the child component?